# Evaluate the $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+x}}-\frac 1x\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ : $$\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+x}}-\frac 1x$$

I have so far $$\frac{x -x\sqrt{1+x}}{x(x\sqrt{1+x})}$$

Do I multiply the numerator and denominator by the conjugate of $x - x\sqrt{1+x}$? Or do I multiply the top and bottom by $x\sqrt{1+x}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get
$$\frac{1}{\color{red}{x}\sqrt{1+x}}-\frac{1}{\color{red}{x}}=\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+x}}-\frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{x\sqrt{1+x}}=\frac{1-\sqrt{1+x}}{x\sqrt{1+x}}.$$
Then, multiply it by $$\frac{1+\sqrt{1+x}}{1+\sqrt{1+x}}.$$

Comment: @user137452: Is there anything unclear?

Comment: What happened to the x's?

Comment: @user137452 I built upon his answer. Please take a look at this for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @user137452: Look at the parts colored in red.

Comment: @user137452: I added a bit again. I hope it helps.

Comment: They first rational expression already has and x. I thought that the x next to the radicand was considered a product?

Comment: I understand thank you.

Comment: @user137452: You are welcome!

Comment: @user84413: Thank you so much:)

Comment: @mathlove You're welcome - thanks for all your great questions and answers.

Answer (score 2):

For $x→0^+$
Here we can use the substitution
$x=\tan^2⁡θ$
$$\lim_{x→0}\dfrac{1}{x√(1+x)}-\dfrac{1}{x}$$
$$=\lim_{θ→0}  \cot^2⁡θ (\cos⁡θ-1)$$
$$=\lim_{θ→0}   \dfrac{\cos^2⁡θ(\cos⁡θ-1)}{\sin^2⁡θ}  $$
$$ \quad\qquad=-\lim_{θ→0}\dfrac{\cos^2⁡θ (\cos⁡θ-1))}{(\cos⁡θ-1)(\cos⁡θ+1)}$$
$$=-\dfrac{1}{2}$$

Comment: The final answer is probably right, but the method you give only gives you the limit as $x \to 0^+$ (because $\tan^2 \theta \ge 0$).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice that.

Comment: If I use the substitution $x=-\sin^2\theta$ then the I can find the left limit also.